# Magento 2 : Check log in customer email id while applying coupon code on cart

Tags: controllers, customer-account, coupon-codes

I want to check customer's email id when he is applying coupon code on cart page.

If customer email is valid for that coupon then coupon code will be apply otherwise display an error.

For this, i tried to overwrite **`CouponPost.php`** controller but getting an error like "Type Error occurred when creating object: `Vendor\Test\Controller\Cart\CouponPost\Interceptor`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To override your `CouponPost.php` controller file you can add `preference` in di.xml file here..

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

Content for this file is..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\CouponPost" type="Vendor\Module\Controller\Cart\CouponPost" />
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Cart/CouponPost.php

Content for this file is..

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Cart;

class CouponPost extends \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\CouponPost
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator $formKeyValidator,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\SalesRule\Model\CouponFactory $couponFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $scopeConfig,
            $checkoutSession,
            $storeManager,
            $formKeyValidator,
            $cart,
            $couponFactory,
            $quoteRepository
        );
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $couponCode = $this->getRequest()->getParam('remove') == 1
            ? ''
            : trim($this->getRequest()->getParam('coupon_code'));

        $cartQuote = $this->cart->getQuote();
        $oldCouponCode = $cartQuote->getCouponCode();

        $codeLength = strlen($couponCode);
        if (!$codeLength && !strlen($oldCouponCode)) {
            return $this->_goBack();
        }

        try {
            $isCodeLengthValid = $codeLength && $codeLength <= \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart::COUPON_CODE_MAX_LENGTH;

            $itemsCount = $cartQuote->getItemsCount();
            if ($itemsCount) {
                $cartQuote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
                $cartQuote->setCouponCode($isCodeLengthValid ? $couponCode : '')->collectTotals();
                $this->quoteRepository->save($cartQuote);
            }

            if ($codeLength) {
                $escaper = $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Escaper::class);
                $coupon = $this->couponFactory->create();
                $coupon->load($couponCode, 'code');
                if (!$itemsCount) {
                    if ($isCodeLengthValid && $coupon->getId()) {
                        $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->setCouponCode($couponCode)->save();
                        $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(
                            __(
                                'You used coupon code "%1".',
                                $escaper->escapeHtml($couponCode)
                            )
                        );
                    } else {
                        $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
                            __(
                                'The coupon code "%1" is not valid.',
                                $escaper->escapeHtml($couponCode)
                            )
                        );
                    }
                } else {
                    if ($isCodeLengthValid && $coupon->getId() && $couponCode == $cartQuote->getCouponCode()) {
                        $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(
                            __(
                                'You used coupon code "%1".',
                                $escaper->escapeHtml($couponCode)
                            )
                        );
                    } else {
                        $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
                            __(
                                'The coupon code "%1" is not valid.',
                                $escaper->escapeHtml($couponCode)
                            )
                        );
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('You canceled the coupon code.'));
            }
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('We cannot apply the coupon code.'));
            $this->_objectManager->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class)->critical($e);
        }

        return $this->_goBack();
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this Error

> Type Error occurred when creating object: Vendor\Test\Controller\Cart\CouponPost\Interceptor

Simply Run this COmmand

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
chmod -R 0777 var/ pub/ generated/
```